# On MCPE how do you refund in-app purchasing?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to uninstall the Festive-Mash Up in MCPE but I don't know how. The Festive-Mash Up is quite out of date.

Comment: I can't think of any app stores which let you refund in-app purchases for no particular reason.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to refund an in-app purchase unless you have a serious problem with it (it's not working, it's not appearing in game etc).

No major store allows you to refund a purchase you made, months after using it just because you think the content (which is intended to represent a season) out of date.